# HTTP Callout Problems in Pre-release

Tags: callout, http, httprequest, spring14, httpresponse

I am running the same code in two different environments and I am getting different results. I have the following code hitting the [REST API exposed on StackExchange](http://api.stackexchange.com/):

```
Http httpQuestions = new Http();
HttpRequest requestQuestions = new HttpRequest();
requestQuestions.setEndpoint('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/605/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=salesforce');
requestQuestions.setMethod('GET');
requestQuestions.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
HTTPResponse responseQuestions = httpQuestions.send(requestQuestions);
System.debug('Get Questions: ' + responseQuestions.getBody());
```

Basically, what this should do is call out to the API and return all of the questions I have asked (my user Id is 605). When I run this code in Execute Anonymous in Winter '14, the request returns a [200 response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success) and I get the following from the debug statement (ran it through [JSONPrettyPrint](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) for readability):

```
15:56:49:374 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|Get Questions: {
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "pre-release"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 224,
      "accepted_answer_id": 25486,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 4,
      "last_activity_date": 1391032089,
      "creation_date": 1390247152,
      "question_id": 24668,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/24668\/writing-apex-in-spring-14-prerelease-org",
      "title": "Writing Apex in Spring &#39;14 Prerelease Org"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "soql",
        "lookup"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 110,
      "accepted_answer_id": 25011,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 4,
      "last_activity_date": 1390542679,
      "creation_date": 1390521475,
      "question_id": 25001,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/25001\/nested-soql-query-on-object-w-lookup-to-same-object",
      "title": "Nested SOQL Query On Object w\/ Lookup To Same Object"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "salesforce1-app"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 196,
      "accepted_answer_id": 23865,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 4,
      "last_activity_date": 1389706625,
      "creation_date": 1389274614,
      "question_id": 23864,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/23864\/set-standard-objects-as-menu-item-in-salesforce1",
      "title": "Set Standard Objects as Menu Item in Salesforce1?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "lookup",
        "page-layout",
        "create-records"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 71,
      "accepted_answer_id": 22462,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 6,
      "last_activity_date": 1387298696,
      "creation_date": 1387298188,
      "last_edit_date": 1387298510,
      "question_id": 22460,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/22460\/modify-new-object-layout-through-lookup",
      "title": "Modify &quot;New&quot; Object Layout through Lookup"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "soql",
        "sosl"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 5567,
      "accepted_answer_id": 9029,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 16,
      "last_activity_date": 1385919473,
      "creation_date": 1362021485,
      "question_id": 9028,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/9028\/soql-vs-sosl-which-one-to-use-and-when",
      "title": "SOQL vs SOSL - Which one to use and when?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "visualforce"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 3323,
      "protected_date": 1382362080,
      "accepted_answer_id": 8140,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 38,
      "last_activity_date": 1382351724,
      "creation_date": 1360161554,
      "last_edit_date": 1360249961,
      "question_id": 8139,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/8139\/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce",
      "title": "Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "leads",
        "lead-conversion"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 213,
      "accepted_answer_id": 17800,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 6,
      "last_activity_date": 1381175720,
      "creation_date": 1381173961,
      "question_id": 17799,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/17799\/multiple-contacts-per-lead-possible",
      "title": "Multiple Contacts Per Lead - Possible?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "ide"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 1702,
      "protected_date": 1377220053,
      "accepted_answer_id": 15659,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 61,
      "last_activity_date": 1379438764,
      "creation_date": 1376944562,
      "last_edit_date": 1376949857,
      "question_id": 15654,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/15654\/force-com-ide-still-officially-supported",
      "title": "Force.com IDE - Still Officially Supported?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "apex",
        "unit-test",
        "batch",
        "api-27"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 1624,
      "accepted_answer_id": 8978,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 7,
      "last_activity_date": 1368082166,
      "creation_date": 1361912702,
      "last_edit_date": 1365153475,
      "question_id": 8959,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/8959\/no-mass-mail-permission-error-from-unit-test-on-singlemailmessage",
      "title": "NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION Error from Unit Test on SingleMailMessage"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "developer-console",
        "api-27"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 1144,
      "protected_date": 1362776429,
      "accepted_answer_id": 9191,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 16,
      "last_activity_date": 1365700479,
      "creation_date": 1362156576,
      "last_edit_date": 1362166843,
      "question_id": 9131,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/9131\/developer-console-issues-in-chrome-spring-13",
      "title": "Developer Console - Issues in Chrome Spring &#39;13?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "deployment",
        "migration-tool"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 418,
      "accepted_answer_id": 10187,
      "answer_count": 3,
      "score": 11,
      "last_activity_date": 1364654401,
      "creation_date": 1364565408,
      "last_edit_date": 1364565843,
      "question_id": 10170,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/10170\/deploy-to-production-cancel-deploy-after-test-failure",
      "title": "Deploy to Production - Cancel Deploy After Test Failure"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "apex",
        "approval-process"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 574,
      "accepted_answer_id": 8152,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 3,
      "last_activity_date": 1363279254,
      "creation_date": 1360170102,
      "last_edit_date": 1360174891,
      "question_id": 8150,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/8150\/programmatically-stopping-approval-process-email",
      "title": "Programmatically Stopping Approval Process Email"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "ide"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 122,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 1,
      "last_activity_date": 1362633144,
      "creation_date": 1362585799,
      "question_id": 9278,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/9278\/force-com-ide-easy-push-of-single-file-through-single-key-combo",
      "title": "Force.com IDE - Easy Push of Single File Through Single Key Combo?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "apex",
        "unit-test",
        "developer-console"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 365,
      "accepted_answer_id": 9151,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 6,
      "last_activity_date": 1362265094,
      "creation_date": 1362162793,
      "question_id": 9136,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/9136\/force-a-unit-test-to-run-immediately-inside-salesforce-web-ui",
      "title": "Force a Unit Test to run immediately inside Salesforce Web UI?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "deployment",
        "migration-tool",
        "package"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 535,
      "accepted_answer_id": 9057,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 6,
      "last_activity_date": 1362061078,
      "creation_date": 1362060569,
      "question_id": 9056,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/9056\/sfretrieve-gets-a-file-but-sfdeploy-cant-find-it-for-the-deploy",
      "title": "sf:retrieve gets a file, but sf:deploy can&#39;t find it for the deploy?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "metadata-api",
        "migration-tool"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 708,
      "accepted_answer_id": 8791,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 5,
      "last_activity_date": 1361459880,
      "creation_date": 1361457257,
      "question_id": 8783,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/8783\/full-list-of-all-accessible-types-through-metadata-api",
      "title": "Full List of All Accessible Types Through Metadata Api"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "site.com"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 353,
      "bounty_amount": 50,
      "accepted_answer_id": 8022,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 7,
      "last_activity_date": 1359983695,
      "creation_date": 1358274012,
      "last_edit_date": 1359745295,
      "question_id": 7264,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/7264\/site-com-incorrectly-escaping-image-urls",
      "title": "Site.com - Incorrectly Escaping Image URLs"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "deployment",
        "migration-tool",
        "migration"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 190,
      "accepted_answer_id": 7982,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 3,
      "last_activity_date": 1359756293,
      "creation_date": 1359745845,
      "question_id": 7971,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/7971\/ant-migration-tool-order-of-package-xml-file-matter",
      "title": "Ant Migration Tool - Order of Package.xml File Matter?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "search"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 9106,
        "user_id": 605,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 95,
        "profile_image": "http:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/2xQqK.png?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Jesse Altman",
        "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/users\/605\/jesse-altman"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 603,
      "accepted_answer_id": 7641,
      "answer_count": 1,
      "score": 1,
      "last_activity_date": 1359042717,
      "creation_date": 1358523859,
      "question_id": 7417,
      "link": "http:\/\/salesforce.stackexchange.com\/questions\/7417\/customizing-global-search",
      "title": "Customizing Global Search"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 300,
  "quota_remaining": 299
}
```

When I run that same exact code in Spring '14, I get a [403 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) with the following from the debug statement:

```
19:06:24.142 (142925130)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|Get Questions: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}--></STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
<P>
While trying to retrieve the URL:
<A HREF="http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/605/questions?">http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/605/questions?</A>
<P>
The following error was encountered:
<UL>
<LI>
<STRONG>
Access Denied.
</STRONG>
<P>
Access control configuration prevents your request from
being allowed at this time.  Please contact your service provider if
you feel this is incorrect.
</UL>
<P>Your cache administrator is <A HREF="mailto:root">root</A>. 


<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<ADDRESS>
Generated Wed, 09 Apr 2014 23:06:24 GMT by proxy-sfm.net.salesforce.com (squid)
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

In both scenarios, I have the Remote Site Details set up as:

[image: Remote Site Details]

The interesting thing about the Spring '14 scenario is that the HTML that gets returned from the 403 error indicates that `http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/605/questions?` is the URL that is getting called. It appears to be dropping the URL query parameters when making the call out. Has anyone seen anything else like this? Is it possible I am missing something really simple? I haven't done a ton with callouts in Apex to be honest, so I am not sure if I am just doing something wrong or if I found a bug.

Comment: might be an internal issue, what Spring '14 instance are you on?

Comment: https://prerelna1.pre.salesforce.com/

Comment: I just tested on a Sandbox (CS14) on Spring 14 and it worked fine there.

Comment: If it matters, my dev org on Winter '14 is on https://na15.salesforce.com

Comment: @DanielHoechst That is really interesting... Maybe what Ryan said is correct. Maybe it is a prerelna1 issue?

Comment: It looks like the response you got in prerel might be from a proxy server. Maybe the proxy isn't configured correctly.

Comment: @DanielHoechst that could be an issue, I'm not really sure

Comment: pre-rel doesn't have the same internet access as production, you are being blocked by the pre-rel outbound proxy

Comment: DanielHoechst or superfell - one of you mind posting that as an answer? I'll give you the checkmark

Comment: @DanielHoechst see above comment

Comment: @superfell see above comment

Comment: If you want you can also use http://jsonprettyprint.net to pretty print. Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call out from a pre-release org, since the security rules are different from our production/developer environments.

Comment: Ah - I just read the comments and saw that @superfell had already given the same answer... Should I delete my answer and let Simon earn the points?

Comment: no need for that.