# Unable to call C# web service

Tags: webservices, c#

I am trying to invoke an asmx web service via button click in a visualforce page. But i am getting that error:

```
Access control configuration prevents your request from
being allowed at this time.  Please contact your service provider if
you feel this is incorrect.
```

What can cause this problem ? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: did you add the webservice endpoint to Remote Site Settings ? also check this [previous discussion](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/http-callout-problems-in-pre-release) and see if it helps you

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Yes i did.

Comment: Are you using Apex to invoke the web service? Is it SOAP or REST based? Can you call the web service from outside of Salesforce? Are you in a [pre-release org?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32358/http-callout-problems-in-pre-release) If you can provide some more details and context it will be easier to help.

Comment: @DanielBallinger yes i am using APEX. It is SOAP based. I can call the web service via manuel invoking.I am in summer release org.